# JPanel inside a JPanel inside a JScrollPane, not able to scroll

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I have JPanel wrapped in a JScrollPane, and I'm creating instances my items which use a JPanel, but when I place these into the JPanel wrapped inside a JScrollPane, the JScrollPane won't allow me to scroll.

Image:
[image: http://i.gyazo.com/a276cd66e4ecd3473698b85dec0c4b7c.png]

Here's the code of my shop item:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class ShopItem extends JPanel {

        private JPanel shopItemPanel;
        private JPanel panelPlaced;
        private JButton btnPurchase;
        private JLabel priceLabel;
        private JTextPane descPane;
        private JLabel attrLabel;
        private TitledBorder titledBorder;

        private int posX;
        private int posY;
        private int shopCatId;
        private int itemId;
        private String itemName;
        private int price;
        private String attribute;
        private int owned;
        private String description;
        private JLabel ownedLabel;

        public ShopItem(int posX, int posY, JPanel panelPlaced, int shopCatId, int itemId, String itemName, int price, String attribute, int owned, String description) {
                this.setPosX(posX);
                this.setPosY(posY);
                this.shopCatId = shopCatId;
                this.itemId = itemId;
                this.itemName = itemName;
                this.price = price;
                this.attribute = attribute;
                this.owned = owned;
                this.description = description;

                shopItemPanel = new JPanel();
                titledBorder = new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), this.itemName, TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 0, 0));
                shopItemPanel.setBorder(titledBorder);
                shopItemPanel.setBounds(posX, posY, 170, 253);
                shopItemPanel.setLayout(null);

                btnPurchase = new JButton("Purchase");
                btnPurchase.setBounds(40, 219, 89, 23);
                shopItemPanel.add(btnPurchase);

                priceLabel = new JLabel("Price: $"+this.price);
                priceLabel.setBounds(10, 21, 147, 14);
                shopItemPanel.add(priceLabel);

                descPane = new JTextPane();
                descPane.setEditable(false);
                descPane.setBounds(10, 93, 147, 115);
                descPane.setText(this.description);
                shopItemPanel.add(descPane);

                attrLabel = new JLabel("Att: "+this.attribute);
                attrLabel.setBounds(10, 46, 150, 14);
                shopItemPanel.add(attrLabel);

                ownedLabel = new JLabel("Owned: "+this.owned);
                ownedLabel.setBounds(10, 71, 150, 14);
                shopItemPanel.add(ownedLabel);

                panelPlaced.repaint();
        }

        public void remove() {
                Shop.getShopItems().remove(this);
                this.panelPlaced.remove(this.shopItemPanel);
                this.panelPlaced.repaint();
        }

        public int getPrice() {
                return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(int price) {
                this.price = price;
        }

        public String getAttribute() {
                return attribute;
        }

        public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
                this.attribute = attribute;
        }

        public int getOwned() {
                return owned;
        }

        public void setOwned(int owned) {
                this.owned = owned;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
                return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
                this.description = description;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
                return itemName;
        }

        public void setItemName(String itemName) {
                this.itemName = itemName;
        }

        public int getItemId() {
                return itemId;
        }

        public void setItemId(int itemId) {
                this.itemId = itemId;
        }

        public int getShopCatId() {
                return shopCatId;
        }

        public void setShopCatId(int shopCatId) {
                this.shopCatId = shopCatId;
        }

        public JPanel getPanelPlaced() {
                return panelPlaced;
        }

        public void setPanelPlaced(JPanel panelPlaced) {
                this.panelPlaced = panelPlaced;
        }

        public JPanel getShopItemPanel() {
                return shopItemPanel;
        }

        public void setShopItemPanel(JPanel shopItemPanel) {
                this.shopItemPanel = shopItemPanel;
        }

        public int getPosX() {
                return posX;
        }

        public void setPosX(int posX) {
                this.posX = posX;
        }

        public int getPosY() {
                return posY;
        }

        public void setPosY(int posY) {
                this.posY = posY;
        }

        public TitledBorder getTitledBorder() {
                return titledBorder;
        }

        public void setTitledBorder(TitledBorder titledBorder) {
                this.titledBorder = titledBorder;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Post the code for your interface , there is no way to tell whats wrong just by looking at that picture .

Comment: Included my shop item class.

Comment: Please post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here with your question, not in a link. Links can go dead, and links may hold large programs, programs too large to ask a volunteer to review.

Comment: I'll do it for you this time as you're new, but in the future, please put in the effort to make it as easy as possible for folks to help you. Please remember that we're all volunteers, so making it easy for others to help is really your responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you're adding anything to a JScrollPane in the code you've posted, but I do see an awful lot of `setBounds(...)` calls as well as `setLayout(null)`, meaning you're setting an absolute size of a component, and this will prevent components from expanding properly when inside of a JScrollPane. Solution: don't do this. Use the layout managers, avoid use of null layouts.

You should avoid use of null layout as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.

For instance, consider creating an inner JPanel that uses a `GridLayout(1, 0)` -- which stands for one row and variable columns, and I'd add my test shop JPanels to it. I'd then add this inner JPanel to the JScrollPane, and add my test shop JPanels into it when needed, calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after each and every addition.

Other suggestions:

- You're mixing your model with your view. Consider creating a non-GUI class, say called ShopItem, that has no GUI anything in it, that has the key logical fields for any ShopItem object such as: `int shopCatId, int itemId, String itemName, int price, String attribute, int owned, String description` fields.
- Consider creating a GUI class that holds and displays one ShopItem object, perhaps called ShopItemView, that either extends or easily returns a JPanel, that can display all the data of a ShopItem object, that allows the user to set it with a different ShopItem object, thus changing the view.
- JTextAreas are much easier to work with than JTextPanes, and so if the text displayed won't require anything fancy, if all will be displayed with the same font, then I'd go with a JTextArea, and I'd set its column and row properties, and never its bounds or sizes.
- And I'd wrap my text component in its own JScrollPane, no matter whether its a JTextArea or JTextPane.
- If using a JTextArea, I'd call `setLineWrap(true)` and `setWrapStyleWord(true)` on it so that it would automatically wrap text.

Comment: Commenting out the setBounds(...) method doesn't show my shop items at all.

Comment: @callumjackson: of course, because you're still using null layouts. Your solution won't be that simple. Instead you'll want to use an appropriate mix of layout managers to help correct size and place your components.